# What's new in Hibernate ORM 5?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-5.x

I just saw that the 4th candidate got released for Hibernate 5. What's new in 5 compared to earlier versions?

Comment: You can find info about changes of new version by googling 'hibernte 5 changelog'. Here it is: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/changelog.txt

Comment: They removed autocommit unless you specify it, and they didn't document the change. Prepare to be screwed hard if you depended on that feature.

Comment: The lists are already long, but I think entity/unrelated joins is a very interesting and noteworthy feature that was introduced in 5.1.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Some exciting features has been added/enhanced in Hibernate 5.x. Have a quick look.

### 1. Hibernate Search

> Hibernate Search transparently indexes your objects and offers fast regular, full-text and geolocation search. Ease of use and easy clustering are core.

- Full-text search for entities - *find by approximation (fuzzy search)*
- Cluster-friendly - *offers several easy to setup clustering strategies*
- Faceting and geolocation - *Geolocalized entities are as easy as @Spatial*

[For more details on Hibernate Search view this.](http://hibernate.org/search/)

### 2. Hibernate Validator

Hibernate Validator comes with a handful of built-in validation rules like Email, Length, NotBlank etc.

> Express validation rules in a standardized way using annotation-based constraints and benefit from transparent integration with a wide variety of frameworks.

[For more details on Hibernate Validator view this.](http://hibernate.org/validator/)

### 3. Improved Java 8 Support

Java 8 date/time data types (JSR 310) are supported and can be validated via @Past and @Future. Also Optional and JavaFX types are supported via an improved ValidatedValueUnwrapper.

### 4. Hibernate OGM

Just released the first stable version.

### 5. Bootstrapping API

New bootstrapping API - better determinism, better integration

---

A few other things:

- Scanning support for non-JPA usage
- NamingStrategy has been removed in favor of a better designed API
- Ability to handle additional Java types for id attributes marked as GenerationType#AUTO. Built-in support for Number and UUID. Expandable via new org.hibernate.boot.model.IdGeneratorStrategyInterpreter extension.
- Additionally, support for AttributeConverters has been expanded and more fully realized

Check [Hibernate ORM Roadmap](http://hibernate.org/orm/roadmap/#hibernate-orm-5-x) for more details.

Comment: but the SessionFacotry still not really serializable! i hope that this should be done in the next version

Answer (score 46):

There's a long list of things that have been changed in Hibernate 5:

1. A new bootstrap API so we can [bootstrap a JPA environment programmatically without the need of a `persistence.xml` file](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-bootstrap-hibernate-without-the-persistence-xml-file/).
2. Starting in 5.0 Hibernate Spatial is part of the Hibernate project so we can handle GIS data too.
3. The [Java 8 Date and Time types](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-java-8-date-and-time-types/) are supported in domain model mappings. The mapping between the standard SQL Date/Time types and the supported Java 8 Date/Time class types looks as follows;

   - DATE: `java.time.LocalDate`
   - TIME: `java.time.LocalTime`, `java.time.OffsetTime`
   - TIMESTAMP: `java.time.Instant`, `java.time.LocalDateTime`, `java.time.OffsetDateTime` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime`
4. The bytecode enhancement mechanism was redesigned from scratch, and Hibernate features both a Maven and a Gradle plugin. There are three main aspects which we can enhance with bytecode instrumentation:

   - Lazy initialization: Fields can be declared as `LAZY` and they will be fetched only when being accessed for the first time.
   - Dirty checking: Entities are enhanced so that they can keep track of all the properties that get changed after being loaded in a Persistence Context.
   - Bidirectional associations: It's possible to synchronize both sides of a bidirectional association automatically, even if the developer only updates a single side.
5. Hibernate's native APIs (`Session`, etc) have been updated to use generic types. No need to cast when fetching entities.
6. Hibernate 5.0 extends this to a broader set of types (e.g. `UUID`).
7. Second-level cache by reference. This feature enables direct storage of entity references into the second level cache for immutable entities.
8. Starting with Hibernate 5.0, we have a completely [new User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) that was written from scratch.

[Hibernate 5.1](http://in.relation.to/2016/02/10/hibernate-orm-510-final-release/) adds the following features:

1. [You can now join unrelated entities in JPQL and HQL queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
2. [Multi-entity load by identififer](http://in.relation.to/2016/02/10/hibernate-orm-510-final-release/)

[Hibernate 5.2](http://in.relation.to/2016/06/01/hibernate-orm-520-final-release/) adds support for:

1. Java 1.8, so [you can now use `Query.stream()`](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/)
2. The Hibernate `Session` extends `EntityManager` so you can get access to all JPA methods right from a `Session`
3. Support for JCache
4. [Session-level batch size](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-the-jdbc-batch-size-for-each-persistence-context-with-hibernate/)
5. [Global timezone setting (e.g. UTC) for `Timestamp` and `Time`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/)
6. [Distinct pass-through hint](http://in.relation.to/2016/08/04/introducing-distinct-pass-through-query-hint/)
7. [More efficient JPQL and HQL parsing of constant values](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-performance-penalty-of-class-forname-when-parsing-jpql-and-criteria-queries/)
8. The [`hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` resource-local transaction optimization](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/).
9. [Better handling of Criteria API literals](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-handle-jpa-criteria-api-literals/).

Comment: Another incompatible change is about the sequence generators, Hibernate 5 defaults to the new enhanced generators and also use the pooled optimizer that is incompatible with previous strategy.

Comment: Yes I was just mentioning this was an important change in Hibernate 5. However instead of disabling the new generator mapping (which log a deprecation warning) I suggest to change the optimizer.