# Support of Hibernate 3.6.1 and upgrading to 5

Tags: java, hibernate

I have application using various libraries including Hibernate 3.6.1. It uses WLS 12 server, Java7, Spring 3.

**I have such libraries:**

- hibernate-core-3.6.1
- hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0GA
- hibernate-jdbc-cacheprovider-1.0.2GA
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.1.00-Final
- hibernate-tools-3.2.4GA
- hibernate-validator-4.1.0

Now I am only talking about Hibernate.I am wondering if it is reasonable to invest some time to upgrade to Hibernate 5. I need to justify it using some strong arguments. Everything works in our project so there is no straight reason for updating, however I think projects should follow library updates if possible.

**My questions are**

1) Is there something like support for bugs in Hibernate 3.6.1 or 4 ? No support would be an argument in favour of upgrading

2) What features could be brought by Hibernate 5 that every PM should be interested in?

3) What other arguments would u bring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Hibernate Validator**

Express validation rules in a standardized way using annotation-based constraints and benefit from transparent integration with a wide variety of frameworks.
For more details on Hibernate Validator view this.

**2. Improved Java 8 Support**

Java 8 date/time data types (JSR 310) are supported and can be validated via @Past and @Future. Also Optional and JavaFX types are supported via an improved ValidatedValueUnwrapper.

**3. Hibernate OGM**

Just released the first stable version.

**4. Bootstrapping API**

New bootstrapping API - better determinism, better integration

Look here for all new features: [What's new in Hibernate ORM 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965179/whats-new-in-hibernate-5)

Comment: Thanks. What about 3.0.6 support - are they fixing any bugs in this version or forgot it and repairing only newest versions by releasing new minor versions ?

Comment: I think they are working on new versions, so all the bugs that are not fixed will be resolved in next releases.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any conflicts between Hibernate 5 and Spring 3.0.6?

Comment: There is a lot of resources to read it ;) you can accept my answer if you want to :)

Comment: One more question - what should be the order of upgrade: Spring3.0.6 to 4, Hibernate 3.6.1 to 5, Java 7 to 8