# Does latest hibernate (5) work with array types?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have following table:

```
   Column    |       Type        |                           Modifiers                           
-------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 product_id  | integer           | not null default nextval('products_product_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying | not null
 description | character varying | not null default ''::character varying
 attributes  | integer[]         | not null
 quantity    | integer           | not null default 0
```

My question is... Does hibernate 5.0.1.final (which ships with latest spring boot) is applicable for integer[] type, or they still didn't make progress on that?

I found out questions about that, but they were asked 3 years ago according hibernate 4. Maybe something changed in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can use array types in Hibernate 5, this is not implimented yet in the new Hibernate, you can learn about that here:

http://hibernate.org/orm/roadmap/#hibernate-orm-5-0

This link also should help you it is about the new things in Hibernate 5:

[What's new in Hibernate ORM 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965179/whats-new-in-hibernate-5)